# Trying to sort object turns into array object

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

This how the default api returns. I want to sort them with basis of `min_conversion_count` properties.
[image: my initial api return]

After sorting the structure changes which is affecting my code. How is it possible to sort them with the property and remain the same format.

Code to sort

```
    var rewarddata = res1.response.reward_list;
// console.log(rewarddata);
sortable_data = [];

console.log(rewarddata);

for (var idx in rewarddata)
{
    sortable_data.push([idx,rewarddata[idx]]);
    sortable_data.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a[1].min_conversion_count - b[1].min_conversion_count;
    });
    console.log(sortable_data);
  }
```

After sorting it changes like this.
[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want to sort them with the property I have mentioned with the same format as first screenshot. How do I do that?

Comment: Object keys don't have an inherent order.  And it's not the sorting that's changing your data structure, it's that you're explicitly converting objects to arrays.

Comment: Objects can't be sorted, only arrays. If you want the items sorted then you'll have to use an array.

Comment: In short, you cannot have a sorted object, as it has no definitive concept of property ordering. You can have a sorted array. Fix your other code to work with an array.

Comment: (Oops, I take it back, times have changed!  Object keys [*do* have an inherent order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key/31102605#31102605), now, turns out.)

Comment: so how can I convert my result into object back.

Comment: so its not possible to have same format like first screenshot even after the data is sorted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You started out with an object, and you put it into an array in order to sort it; once your array is sorted, you have to turn it back into an object.

```
const sortedObj = sortable_data.reduce((accum, [key, value]) => {
  accum[key] = value;
  return accum;
}, {});
```

Note that property ordering is *generally* not something to rely on. It would be better to save an array of the sorted *keys* only, and then use that array instead.

Comment: this returns error on value

Comment: It's just destructuring the two-valued array you pushed in your code here:

`sortable_data.push([idx,rewarddata[idx]]);`
   
Make sure your sortable_data is sorted and in the format you described above first.

Comment: Thanks with couple of tweaks it finally worked :)